# Change the route when button is clicked

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

There is a situation where i have to show the login form when login button is clicked at initial. This can be done when using  but it is already in use to show another form as default. I tried to use  to the login button to show login as default in the modal box where there is an option for both login and signup which uses router to show their ui. But the modal does not appear if i do so. Sorry it might sound confusing to you because of my poor English. Thus i am showing the screenshot to make my problem clear.

This is my button for showing login and signup box which is shown in modal. When i click on the button, the modal pops up

[image]

Now i clicked my button. Let's say i clicked on login then login form should be shown as active/default but it shows empty modal box

[image]

I have to click on iniciar sesion(login) to show login box or Registrarse(sign up) to show sign up box.

Here is my code

nav.js(here is the button)

```
<li className="btn-group">
  <button
    className="btn btn-default"
    onClick={props.showModal}
  >
    Regístrate
  </button>
  <button
    onClick={props.showModal}
    className="btn btn-default"
  >
    Iniciar sesión
  </button>
  {props.show ?
    <ModalForm
      show={props.show}
      onHide={props.onHide}
    /> : <span />
  }
</li>
```

ModalForm.js

```
<Router>
    <Modal
      {...this.props}
      show={show}
      onHide={onHide}
      dialogClassName="custom-modal"
    >
      <Modal.Header closeButton>
        <Link to='/login'>
          <Modal.Title id="contained-modal-title-lg">Iniciar Sesion</Modal.Title>
        </Link>
        <Link to='/signup'>
          <Modal.Title id="contained-modal-title-lg">Registrase</Modal.Title>
        </Link>
      </Modal.Header>
      <Modal.Body>
        <Match pattern='/login' component={Login} />
        <Match pattern='/signup' component={Signup} />
      </Modal.Body>
    </Modal>
</Router>
```

In a nutshell, When clicked on registrate or iniciar sesion, how can i show the their form in the modal ?

**The react router v4 has been used for routing**

Comment: Looks confusing... can you create a fiddle for that ?